# lua error when running Garry's Mod server

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

```
[ERROR] gamemodes/starwarsrp/gamemode/modules/base/sv_gamemode_functions.lua:256: attempt to index local 'jobTable' (a nil value)  
  1. unknown - gamemodes/starwarsrp/gamemode/modules/base/sv_gamemode_functions.lua:256
```

Here is line 256 and 257:

```
 256 if jobTable.ShowSpare2 then
 257      return jobTable.ShowSpare2(ply)
```

Comment: You need to post a minimal, reproducible example if you want to be helped.

Answer (score 0):

`jobTable` is `nil`. It is not allowed to index nil values. That measn you may not write something like `jobTable[1]` or `jobTable.ShowSpare(ply)`.

Either find out why `jobTable` is `nil` in your code or if you cannot ensure it is not nil, avoid indexing it by doing something like

```
if jobTable then return jobTable.ShowSpare(ply)
```

or

```
return jobTable and jobTable.ShowSpare(ply)
```